# Find the DeRham cohomology of the spaces minus a line and a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, de-rham-cohomology

Find the DeRham's cohomology of the following open sets, and then looking at the product conclude that they are not diffeomorphic.

a) $M=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus (L_1\cup C)$,  $L_1=\{x=y=0\}$ and $C=\{x^2+y^2=1,z=0\}$.

b) $N=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus (L_2\cup C)$,  $L_2=\{x=3,y=0\}$ and $C=\{x^2+y^2=1,z=0\}$.

Can you give me an idea?

I tried:

**Idea**
I write
$$M=
\left(\mathbb{R^3}\setminus L_1\right)\cap \left(\mathbb{R^3}\setminus C\right)$$
So I had to find first the cohomology of $\left(\mathbb{R^3}\setminus L_1\right)$ and $\left(\mathbb{R^3}\setminus C\right)$. But I dont how to find them and neither how to use the different positions of the line respecto to the circle

Thank you

Comment: The clue: start with the definition of de Rham cohomology...

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @nomen: your clue is worthless. I challenge you to write a solution, or even to say something non trivial about the problem, just using the definition of de Rham cohomology.

Comment: @Georges: um, what's so hard about cochain complexes on manifolds?  Nothing.

Comment: @nomen You shouldn't say a problem  is not hard unless you can solve it. And I would be very surprised if you could.

Comment: @ArcticChar thank you, there is what i tried.

Comment: @Georges: pardon me for assuming everybody who would ever see this problem would have taken several years of calculus, through Stokes theorem, and would have seen how to calculate short exact cochain complexes for manifolds induced by the exterior derivative.  Makes the problem pretty trivial if I spell it all out...

Comment: Dear Framate: your first idea does not work because $V$ is not open in $\mathbb R^3$,   while Mayer-Vietoris requires **open** coverings..

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg true, i did not realized that open coverings, thank you very much, i will edit.

Comment: I wll try my second idea. I do not understand the part of "looking at the product", do I have to use Kunneth formula?

Comment: Dear Framate: yours is quite a difficult question if you are only allowed to use de Rham cohomology. Was it assigned as an exercise in some course?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thank you for your answer, yes,I only allowes to use de Rham cohomology. I am taking a course called Topology of Manifolds

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some visual hints will help, if you'll excuse the hand-drawn examples...

[image: Visual Hints]

First we see $M$ deformation retracts to a torus. Intuitively, the missing line at $x=y=0$ becomes the hole through the donut, while the missing circle at $x^2+y^2 = 1, z=0$ becomes the hole *inside* the donut.

Next, we consider $N$. Since the circle and the line aren't interlinked, we may consider them separately, and then glue them together at the end with the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence.

On the left, we have $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S^1$, which is "well known" to deformation retract to $S^2 \vee S^1$. Instead of thinking about this as a sphere with a circle on its side, think of it as a sphere with a diameter linking its two poles. Then the missing circle becomes the hollow bit between this diameter and the surface of the sphere... Sorry I don't have a better picture for this. Perhaps the graphics [here](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/clever-homotopy-equivalences) will help. This can also be found on page 46 of Hatcher.

On the right, we have $\mathbb{R}^3$ without a line. This deformation retracts to the plane without a point (by squishing down), and of course this is well known to be a circle. The missing point becomes the hole in the center of the circle.

Do you think you can use this information (as well as the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence for $N$) to discover the cohomology of these spaces, and thereby deduce they aren't diffeomorphic?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Dear @HallaSurvivor thank you very much, i can not use Van Kampen theorem, just DeRham cohomology, MV sequence. But I really really really appreciate your help,  with that, M has the DeRham cohomology of the torus!!!!! I will try with N!!

Comment: Sorry! I misspoke! I didn't mean the van Kampen Theorem, I meant the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence. I'll update my answer now

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to understand!!! :D

Comment: Of course! I'm happy to help ^_^. If you think this answered your question, though, please mark it as accepted so that other people know where to spend their time. Also, feel free to ask follow up questions in the comments.

Comment: Your answer  doesn't  address the de Rham cohomology but is extremely interesting and at least states the required result we should try to prove *à la* de Rham. Hence thank you (also for the link) , dear HallaSurvivor, and +1.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why this doesn't address the de Rham Cohomology. Computing the de Rham Cohomology of a torus, or of R^3 without a line, or of a wedge of S^2 and S^1, is (in my mind) easier than computing the de Rham Cohomology of the given manifolds directly. So my answer "gives OP an idea", as requested. If they are unsure of how to compute the Cohomology of these new manifolds, I will be happy to update my answer, as I've already mentioned.

Comment: De Rham cohomology is about classes of closed differential forms modulo exact ones. Your answer  has nothing to do with de Rham cohomology since differential forms are not alluded to. In fact the notation $S^2 \vee S^1$ doesn't even make sense in De Rham cohomology since that space is not a manifold. Your answer is interesting and  welcome however (and I upvoted it)  because it does indeed give " some visual hints ". But the link to de Rham cohomology is  indirect: it relies on de Rham's powerful theorem of isomorphism in the case of manifolds of "his" cohomology with the classical one.

Comment: That's reasonable. I learned de Rham Cohomology from Bott and Tu, so perhaps I have a skewed idea of what results are and aren't applicable here. In particular, the fact that $S^2 \vee S^1$ isn't a manifold didn't even cross my mind. Thanks for the clarification ^_^

Comment: Thank very much to both of you. I think we are learning, and that is the idea of the site. In fact, I use the homotopy in (a), but for (b) I take $U=R^3\setminus L_1$, $V=R^3\setminus S^1$, so $M=U\cap V$, $U\cup V=\emptyset$. I know that $U=R^3\setminus L_1\equiv R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, and I know its cohomology groups, but i do not know how to find the cohomology groups for $V=R^3\setminus S^1$.